# npm install does not work because certain package does not contain a package.json file

Tags: node.js, npm, prettier

I am trying to run npm install for a cloned project and it errors out with this error: `Could not install from "node_modules/@miksu/prettier/parse-srcset@github:ikatyang/parse-srcset#54eb9c1cb21db5c62b4d0e275d7249516df6f0ee" as it does not contain a package.json file`

I don't have `/node_modules` in this directory since this is the first `npm i` for this project on my local computer. Also I am using vscode and I have this in the package.lock file `@miksu/prettier` but i don't have prettier in the package.json as a package to install. Let me know what other information is needed. Thanks!

Edit: I deleted the `@miksu/prettier` entry from `package-lock.json` and that allowed `npm i` to run successfully, but I'm still not sure what is going on with this error. Any clarity is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I mean... the package it self doesnt contain a package.json

Comment: Not the project, the package it self, the npm i cant install FROM node_modules/@miksu/prettier/parse-srcset@github:ikatyang/parse-srcset#54eb9c1cb21db5c62b4d0e275d7249516df6f0ee, which means that dir doesnt have a package.json. try adding one there

Comment: `node_modules` doesn't exist in the project

Comment: That means that you are trying to install a non-existent module

Comment: how does a package like this end up in my package.lock? how can i fix this? forking the project?